# re-index php keys in array starting with certain number

Tags: php, arrays, reindex

I have an array which has keys starting from 0 upwards. Is there a way to reindex the array to change shift the keys to start from 3 instead of 0?

Comment: are you going to answer any answer ??

Answer (score 1):

Quickly off the top of my head, but there's probably better ways to do it

```
$reindexedArray = array_combine(
    range(3,count($originalArray)+3),
    $originalArray
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
$newArray[$key+3] = $value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```